# Error: path `zenbot:exchanges.undefined` is undefined

Tags: javascript, zenbot

I am running zenbot on ubuntu 16.04, and have installed it according to readme.md
zenbot is basically functional; I can backfill and simulate without specifying the --conf. However, whenever I specify a --conf file (be it the conf.js, the conf-sample.js or any altered version), I get the error

```
$ ./zenbot.sh sim --days 2 --conf ./conf.js gdax.BTC-EUR
/home/xx/GitHub/zenbot/node_modules/codemap/index.js:233
    throw err;
    ^

Error: path `zenbot:exchanges.undefined` is undefined
    at Object.get (/home/xx/GitHub/zenbot/node_modules/codemap/index.js:231:19)
at get (/home/xx/GitHub/zenbot/node_modules/codemap/index.js
```

I can't trace back to what the problem realy is but would be happy to resolve this. Any help and hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue after updating zenbot today.
Zenbot was running fine with codebase from Jan 22, 2018. I would recommend try to check to an older version and try it out

You can run these commands below, that will take you to [this](https://github.com/DeviaVir/zenbot/tree/d600b3cd8ae53434646d479fdfef8a718e8bf756) older version of zenbot.

```
# git checkout d600b3cd8ae53434646d479fdfef8a718e8bf756
# npm install
```

This older version pointed here works for me when I provide the parameters in the arguments, but throws the error you mentioned, when i provide a configuration file to read from like

```
 # ./zenbot.sh sim --conf gdaxbtc.js
```

The latest version of zenbot (on Feb 3, 2018), in it's unstable branch is behaving differently for exchanges. I tested with some of them.

GDAX acts like this now

```
root@kalihost:/opt/zenbot# ./zenbot.sh trade --paper --days 2 gdax.BTC-USD
fetching pre-roll data:
*************************
Hitting up the exchange 'gdax' for trades within the past 1 day.
*************************


Backfilling...


^C
```

With BITTREX it seems that zenbot gets stuck trying to backfill.

```
# ./zenbot.sh trade --paper --days 2 bittrex.BTC-USDT
fetching pre-roll data:
*************************
Hitting up the exchange 'bittrex' for trades within the past 1 day.
*************************


Backfilling...


please note: the bittrex api does not support backfilling (trade/paper only).
please note: make sure to set the --period_length=1m to make sure data for trade/paper is fetched.
^C
```

Poloniex seems to be working fine.

```
# ./zenbot.sh trade --paper
fetching pre-roll data:
*************************
Hitting up the exchange 'poloniex' for trades within the past 1 day.
*************************


Backfilling...




final trade id ==> [undefined]
           DATE            PRICE     DIFF       VOL     RSI                         ACTIONS                      BAL                PROFIT
2018-02-03 14:06:00  9412.00 BTC-USDT                 9                             
2018-02-03 14:08:00  9401.00 BTC-USDT   -0.12%       16                             
2018-02-03 14:10:00  9380.00 BTC-USDT   -0.23%        6                             
2018-02-03 14:12:00  9389.12 BTC-USDT   +0.09%        1
```